# How to approach first and last element of one dimensional numpy array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1 dimensional numpy array. I don't have any information about its first and last element. I want to do slicing. Is there any other way to approach first and last element rather than the following method?
    `a= np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
    b= a.reshape(-1)
    even = b[b[0]:b[len(b):2]]
    odd = b[b[1]:b[len(b)]:2]`

Comment: Uhm, what has your code to do with the question?

Comment: I want to know some other method to do this. In my code I have to separate all values at even position and in second case I have to separate all odd values. I only know the length of array

Comment: first/last or even/odd??

Comment: I do think one-dimensional numpy array support `arr[0]` and `arr[-1] ` to access first and last elements.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the first and last elements of an array,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(100)
print('first element', a[0])
print('Last element', a[-1])
```